# Holonomy groups of compact Riemannian symmetric spaces

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces, holonomy

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian symmetric space. By the classification of Cartan, it belongs to the table of homogeneous spaces given in the Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space

In the Berger classifiction of holonomy groups

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#The_Berger_classification

the symmetric case is omitted because

> the holonomy group can easily be read off the Cartan classification in the symmetric space case.

How does this "reading off" work exactly. Can someone point to me a list of the holonomy groups of the compact symmetric spaces?

Comment: In general, the holonomy group and the isotropy group have the same identity component (this is a theorem of E. Cartan). So if you assume that $M$ is simply-connected, they are equal.

Comment: Plase put this as the answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the request of the OP I put my comment as an answer: in general, the holonomy group and the isotropy group have the same identity component (this is a theorem of E. Cartan). So if you assume that $M$ is simply-connected, they are equal. You can see a proof (for instance) in section 10.79 of Arthur Besse's *Einstein manifolds*.